# Receive message from MQTT in android service

Tags: android, service, push-notification, mqtt

I have to create an Android app that can receive message from a sensor and send a notification to the user when a message is received. I have to do this with out using service like Google Firebase because all the system must run locally. I thought to use MQTT in a service, but when I kill the app, it disconnect from the broker. If the app is running in background this implementation works but I need to keep the connection alive also when app is killed.

This is my implementation of the service:

```
package it.unisalento.sonoff.helper;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.net.wifi.aware.AttachCallback;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.Process;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttDeliveryToken;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttCallbackExtended;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttMessage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import it.unisalento.sonoff.R;
import it.unisalento.sonoff.view.MainActivity;

public class Service extends android.app.Service {
    private Looper serviceLooper;
    private ServiceHandler serviceHandler;
    private List ids = new ArrayList();
    private MqttHelper mqttHelper;

private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
    public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
        super(looper);
    }
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        showNotification("Aggiornamento di stato", String.valueOf(msg.arg1));
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("ServiceStartArguments",
            Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
    thread.start();

    serviceLooper = thread.getLooper();
    serviceHandler = new ServiceHandler(serviceLooper);
    mqttHelper = new MqttHelper(getApplicationContext());

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    mqttHelper = new MqttHelper(getApplicationContext());
    mqttHelper.setCallback(new MqttCallbackExtended() {
        @Override
        public void connectComplete(boolean reconnect, String serverURI) {

        }

        @Override
        public void connectionLost(Throwable cause) {

        }

        @Override
        public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
            Message msg = serviceHandler.obtainMessage();
            msg.arg1 = startId;
            serviceHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        }

        @Override
        public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken token) {

        }
    });
    mqttHelper.connect();

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // We don't provide binding, so return null
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "service done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void showNotification(String title, String message) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    String channelId = "notification_channel";
    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, "lock", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        channel.enableVibration(true);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
    int id;
    if(ids.isEmpty()){
        id=0;
    }
    else{
        id = ids.size();
    }
    ids.add(id);
    notificationManager.notify(id , notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

}

And here my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="it.unisalento.sonoff">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.FullScreen"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

    <!-- MqttService -->
    <service android:name="org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService" />
    <service android:name=".helper.Service"
        android:exported="false"
        android:stopWithTask="false"/>
    <activity android:name=".view.DashboardActivity"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".view.LoginActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".view.MainActivity"/>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Foreground Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services) and pass the notification you built in `startForeground` method.

Comment: Does it keep alive the service even when the app is killed from task manager?

Comment: From the "Force Stop" option? No.
From the Recents page? Yes, but depends on your phone ROM(Chinese ROMs tend to use Force Stop in the background, so even that won't help).